# WPF ItemContainerGenerator One-to-Many Mapping

Tags: .net, wpf, itemscontrol

Is it possible to create an [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611040.aspx) that generates more than one visual item from each data item? I have a collection of custom objects that have two independent visuals that I would like to be added to the same ItemsControl. It is not desirable to display them as their original pairs so it will not be much use to create a template with a panel for each data item that contains the two visuals. However, the two visuals must remain linked to each other, as they respond to each other's events.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM to the rescue here. Wouldn't it be easier to create a VM to display your data in such a way that you can get a 1-to-1 to the view?

I dont know if this is a solution in your specific situation. Maybe with some more detail we can tell...

Comment: You have a model and you want to create 2 partial views of that model that are extreamly well linked but having their own instance and object lifetime. Thats quite tricky because if your model dies, you probably want your views to die with him. As @HighCore said, why do you need 2 views for a single model object... we need more details

Comment: I don't think that will help. I have a collection of objects, each one of which has two separate content properties which, after templating, contain two different visual representations of the same data. I want both visuals to be added as children of the itemscontrol, both linked to the original object, but ItemContainerGenerator seems to only support a 1-to-1 mapping.

Comment: Can you show some code so we can understand better? I don't see how this cannot be achieved using 2 VMs for the same Model